# How to define dependent function in node js?

Tags: javascript, code-quality, node.js, code-reuse

I have a nodejs project in which a sample.js include two function 
function A depends on function B's callback .

```
// smaple.js
        Both function are included in the same file 
        function B ( arg1 , callback ){
            // do some async
            async.map(arg1 , function(item, cb){
                     var a = item.a
                     var b = a*4
                     cb( null , {'a':a,'b':b})  
                },function(err , result){
                callback(err , result)
            } )


        }


        function A ( arg , callback ){
            if(condition1){
            callback(null , 1)
            }else{
             B ( arg , function( err , result){
                if(err){
                 callback(err , result)
                }
                else if (result ==1 ){

                callback ( null , 2)
                }else{
                callback ( null , 1)
                }

             })
            }
        }
```

Scenario 2

```
        // function B is in outer.js and included as module
        sample.js

        var outerfunction = require('./outer.js');

        function A ( arg , callback ){
            if(condition1){
            callback(null , 1)
            }else{
             outerfunction.B ( arg , function( err , result){
                if(err){
                 callback(err , result)
                }
                else if (result ==1 ){

                callback ( null , 2)
                }else{
                callback ( null , 1)
                }

             })
            }
        }


        outer.js


        function B ( arg1 , callback ){
            // do some async
            async.map(arg1 , function(item, cb){
                     var a = item.a
                     var b = a*4
                     cb( null , {'a':a,'b':b})  
                },function(err , result){
                callback(err , result)
            } )


        }

        module.exports.B = B ;
```

Does scenario 1 is a proper way to use function ?
What will happen if this code run concurrently using cluster module?

Does scenario 2 is better way to use dependent function ?
Is this code perform better on concurrent execution?

Comment: In your second scenario,since your dependent function is in another module, you have to add your callback function(functionB in outer.js) to module.exports object. Syntax: module.exports.functionB=function() {}

Comment: Have you thought of async- pattern like waterfall ?

Answer (score 1):

Both cases will do. You just have to maintain the chain of methods to execute.

If you have one method dependent on another method, one of the way's of maintaining the chain is to call the second method inside the callback to the firs one just like you are doing I believe:

**Example:**

```
function bar(param) {
    console.log(param);
}

function foo(param, done) {
    if(param === 1) {
        return done(param);
    }
}

foo(1, bar);
```